# Unable to open a hibernate session

Tags: hibernate, session, dropwizard, named-query

The following is my DAO class

```
public class AppDAO extends AbstractDAO<App>{

    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public Session session;

    public ServiceDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

public List<String> getNames(Long id) {
        List<String> names= list(namedQuery("query.to.get.rows.").setParameter("id",id));
        return names;
    }
```

I am trying to use this in another class in the following way

```
public AnotherClass {

AppDAO dao;
public AnotherClass(AppDAO dao) {
this.dao = dao;
}

public List<String> someMethod() {
dao.getByName();

}
```

This gives a "No session bound to execution context error" what am I missing>. I tried to log the session object inside the getNmaes() method and see that it is not null. What should I do to make the namedQuery pick up the current session? Have I missed any annotation? My resource method is annotated with @UnitOfWork. IS there anything else?

The stackTrace

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext.currentSession(ManagedSessionContext.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
```

The named Query

@NamedQuery (name = "query.to.get.rows",
             query = "SELECT a.name FROM APP")

Comment: could you please rather paste the stacktrace?

Comment: and actually code for `namedQuery` and `list` would be nice

Comment: I added the stack trace and the named Queru. List is just giving back the result as a java ArrayList

Comment: That abstract dao is a class of yours? It looks lite it would use different session factory then the one you are passing in the constructor. Is `getNames` caller is the same thread that is creating `AppDao`? `ManagedSessionContext` is "thread-sensitive" so it cares about calling threads.

Comment: I am using hibernate under the hod of dropwizard so I dont have to configure a hibernate.cfg. Also read http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.0/dropwizard-hibernate/apidocs/io/dropwizard/hibernate/AbstractDAO.html for AbstractDAO. I am using the same sessionfactory by saying "super(sessionFactory)"

Comment: The same session factory yes, but maybe not session created for your "session existance check" in `this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();`
Quoting here: "I tried to log the session object inside the getNmaes() method and see that it is not null."
Did you log `this.session` or `this.currentSession()` this is the difference and probably the second one would throw the same exception. However, as this is framework class, it should handle new session creation in case when there is none for current thread. Wierd